# Printing limited number of words in String

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming, and i am having a hard time with a project due in class.  I have a synopsis retrieved from a netflix WSDL, and my task is to limit it from a large paragraph to only 10 words.

In other words, what code should I use to limit a large string to a specific number of words?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried any code.  Honestly, the professor doesn't teach the class well and the students are left to look up most of the information via book and online resources.  I've been at the project since 1:00pm and this is my last step and I can't figure it out.

Comment: That's what I would call a good teacher. I've seen students in their third year not even knowing that javadoc existed. Reading and understanding documentation is one of the things you really need to know. If you can do that, you'll be able to learn by yourself for your wole career. If your teacher tells you how to use the String methods without making you search and discover by yourself, you'll know how to use String, and that's all.

Comment: To what 10 words do you want to limit the large string?

Answer (score 6):

The only tool you really need is the `String.split()` method.

You split the String by a blank space delimiter, i.e. `" "`, if `resultingArray.length <= 10` you save the first 10, discard the rest.

Simple :)

#### Edit: As this is not a homework service, you need to show some good faith. The usage of String.split however is seen below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String sentence = "This is a really, really, really, super line";
    final String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("Word %d: %s\n", i, words[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this code look typed out though?  The name of the lengthy string is Synopsis.

Comment: I've updated the post, that is more than enough information for you :)